# How to read data from a form?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I have a php script which will make my telegramm bot send a message:

```
<?php
$botToken = "<my_bot_token_here>";
$website = "http://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
$chat_id = 25665198;
file_get_contents($website.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chat_id.'&text='.$_POST["message"]);
```

I want to decide what message will be sent so I created a form:

```
 <form action="telegram.php" method="post">
     Message: <input type="text" name="message" />
     <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

But for some reason the script does not work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: var_dump the post variable to see if something gets send. Some other hints: don't public your private bot token. escape the URL params.

Comment: You should have some check on `telegram.php` that authenticates the user. This currently will allow any user/bot to send messages.

Comment: you have to use https scheme for telegram API: `https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/METHOD_NAME` - in docs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is just https instead of http on $website. So change it into:

```
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".$botToken;
```

Moreover change last line into something like this:

```
$output = file_get_contents($website.'/sendmessage?chat_id='.$chat_id.'&text='.$_POST["message"]);
if($output == false) ? echo "Something gone Wrong" : echo $output;
```

In this way you will see the result of **file_get_contents()**